# Logica SMPP error relating to a missing class

Tags: java, runtime-error, smpp

I am developing mobile application that will interact with an smsc through the shortcode feature.

Since I cannot afford to get a shortcode, I decided to use the Logica SMPP server

So am trying to run the **Logica SMPP** test application first to get some idea of sending and processing text messages.

But I get and error as seen in the screen shot

[image: Logica SMPP error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear from the screenshot what full command you used. I am assuming the following:

```
java -cp smpp.jar:smpptest.jar:smscsim.jar com.logica.smpp.test.SMPPTest
```

Since you are on Windows, semicolon (;) is the correct jar file separator, not colon (:) which works on Linux.

So, the correct command is:

```
java -cp smpp.jar;smpptest.jar;smscsim.jar com.logica.smpp.test.SMPPTest
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this has already been answered but I would recommend using SMPPSim as its easier to use than Logica and has a web interface that you can use to interact with the smpp simulator. Take a look. Its been very helpful to me in the last few days. http://www.seleniumsoftware.com/downloads.html

Ive been learning smpp for the last few weeks and finally managed to get most of my application working because of it ^^

Good luck

Comment: It is not available any more. Some option in these nowadays?